# autotools syntax error with ax_check_compile_flag

Tags: c++, linux, autotools, configure

I am using autotools for building my C++ application. In my **configure.ac** I have the following line:

```
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-Wall], [CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -Wall"])
```

which causes the following error when executing **./configure** (after running *autoreconf -i*):

```
./configure: line 3825: syntax error near unexpected token `-Wall,'
./configure: line 3825: `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG(-Wall, CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -Wall")'
```

My system: *Linux web 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux*

On my Ubuntu machine it works well, why do I get this error?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`autoreconf` isn't magic (though I encounter package maintainers who obviously believe this).  When you ran `autoreconf`, it failed to find the `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` macro, and produced a corrupt `configure` script.  Usually that produces an error/diagnostic message at the same time.

'AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` comes from the [autoconf archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_check_compile_flag.html) project, and Debian has a package which provides this, named [autoconf-archive](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=autoconf-archive).  Likely, you forgot to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf-archive
```

Comment: Just want to add, for anyone using this solution, you do need to re-run autoconf after installing autoconf-archive.