# Why am I getting the following syntax error with autoconf?

Tags: autoconf

I have the following line in autoconf:

```
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-std=c++0x], [CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++0x"], AC_MSG_ERROR([Need C++11 support]))
```

aclocal, autoconf and automake -a -c go smoothly.

However, when I run configure, I get the error:

```
./configure: line 2142: syntax error near unexpected token `-std=c++0x,'
./configure: line 2142: `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG(-std=c++0x, CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++0x", as_fn_error $? "Need C++11 support" "$LINENO" 5)'
```

Any ideas why?

EDIT: This seems to be different than the other questions, because

```
   AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG(-std=c++0x)
```

by itself works...

EDIT:

Here is a full configure.ac

```
# initial information about the project
AC_INIT([myproject],[0.1],[project@gmail.com])

# check if the source folder is available
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/main.cpp])

# check for C++ preprocessor and compiler
CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++0x"
CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -O3"

AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-std=c++0x], [CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++0x"], AC_MSG_ERROR([Need C++11 support]))

AC_PROG_CXXCPP
AC_PROG_CXX

AC_PROG_CC

# automake initialization (mandatory) including a check for automake API version >= 1.9
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.9])


# use the C++ compiler for the following checks
AC_LANG([C++])

# Checks for header files.
AC_HEADER_STDC
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([string])
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([iostream])

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T

# distribute additional compiler and linker flags among Makefiles
# --> set and change these variables instead of CXXFLAGS or LDFLAGS (for user only)
AC_SUBST([AM_CXXFLAGS])
AC_SUBST([AM_LDFLAGS])

# files to generate via autotools (prepare .am or .in source files)
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([src/Makefile])

# finally this generates the Makefiles etc. for the build
AC_OUTPUT
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [autotools syntax error with ax\_check\_compile\_flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412576/autotools-syntax-error-with-ax-check-compile-flag)

Comment: Your `configure.ac` fails for me in the manner you describe when the `ax_check_compile_flag.m4` is not installed in `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR`.  Does not error for me when `ax_check_compile_flag.m4` is installed in `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR`.  Now convinced it's a duplicate.

Comment: BTW, automake 1.9 is like a decade old.  You should set `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` to something more recent.

Answer (score 0):

That does not seem likely that it's a not the same, as if you do have `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` defined in your autoconf search corpus, you would not even find a reference to it in the `configure` file at all.

But, you also have multiple spaces in front of the second example you give, which suggests me that you possibly have this in a conditional block, or following another macro or conditional block. Any other undefined macro in the `configure.ac` file may cause autoconf to emit a macro as literal, rather than expanding it as you expect it to. I would suggest you post a full, reduced `configure.ac` that shows the behaviour, rather than just one line.