# Compile Vala from sources on Linux Mint 18.3

Tags: vala

I've always been able to compile sources from git repository https://github.com/GNOME/vala.git on my PC running "Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit".  I have the latest valac (0.42.4-0ubuntu1~16.04~valateam0) installed.

The last successful compile I did was from version 0.40.0.257-40b5-dirty. Today, I downloaded the latest vala.git, but when i run ./configure I get:

```
./configure: line 12579: syntax error near unexpected token `$flag,TEST_CFLAGS="$TEST_CFLAGS $flag"'
./configure: line 12579: `  AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG($flag,TEST_CFLAGS="$TEST_CFLAGS $flag")'
```

Do I need to make additional environment changes? Not sure were to go from here.

Comment: Questions about installing software on Linux is off topic even though it's about a programming tool. Your problem is with Ubuntu Linux so you should ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compiling Vala from source is a good start in contributing back to the Vala project. Vala currently uses autotools as its build system. For Ubuntu `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` is provided by a separate package: `autoconf-archive`. See the [autotools syntax error with ax_check_compile_flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412576/autotools-syntax-error-with-ax-check-compile-flag) answer on Stack Overflow for more details. So you should just need to install `autoconf-archive`.

By the way the main repository for Vala is in GNOME's GitLab instance: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala You may want to clone that one instead. The GitLab instance also allows issues to be raised and merge requests to be submitted.